# Samba connection slowness after ip change

Tags: networking, samba

we have encountered with a problem when we chaged the samba server's ip address. There are so many OS varies from Windows,GNU/Linux, Solaris and IBM.

The samba server is running on SOlaris. And all changes has made on host after Samba server's ip address change procedure. After the ip address change process,  the samba connections slowed. And sometimes connection is getting time out.

When we get back the ip address to the old format, everything works like a charm.

We have deletede samba caches but we cannot find a solution for this case. What would you offer for this problem.

Is there anybody that have encountered like this situation before  ?

Comment: have you checked logs when you facing this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

If the new address is in a different subnet, it might be possible that your network administrator is imposing a set of QoS rules that throttle the traffic to this subnet (or even to this specific ip address). I think it might be easier for people to help you if you give more context about the issue you face:

-are the 2 addresses in the same subnet
-if yes, are there any traffic shaping rule in your network
-is the slowness specific to the samba server, is any type of connection to the whole server experiencing the same latency ?